# Source Control Explorer Keeps refreshing and flickering with every change

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

We have TFS 2012 update 3 on premises, I'm using VS 2012 update 3, the only extensions I have are TFS Power tools 2012.2 and VS Productivity Tools 11.0.60403.0.

With every change (check out for edit, delete, check-in) the Folders section (Treview on the left) of Source Control Explorer keeps refreshing and flickering.

I have 89572 files on my workspace and I always have more than one instance of VS open, so after reading this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phkelley/archive/2013/05/31/tf400030-the-local-data-store-is-currently-in-use-by-another-operation.aspx) I changed my workspace to server, but the problem did not stop.

In short, Source Control Explorer is driving me crazy, with every little change I have to wait something like 10 seconds until the flickering stops.

Does anybody has any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Are your machine resources spiking?

Comment: The CPU is usually around 15% (Core i7 2760QM), memory usage is about 30% (I have 16GB), and I also have an SSD.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I've got the same thing.

Comment: No, I disabled the hardware acceleration in VS but everything remains the same, I have to close VS every 2 to 3 hours

Comment: I have seen this happen in VS 2013 as well. I'd be interested to know what's happening. If I find something, I'll try and post it here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS is apparently aware of the issue and claims to be working on a fix.

http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/803702/source-control-explorer-left-hand-tree-flickers-and-locks-up-every-time-i-check-in-a-pending-change

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround that in my case worked.

After adding a new working folder to my workspace through File > Source Control > Advanced > Worspaces... > Edit... the problem was gone.

Maybe opening the workspace and press OK is enough.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to add a new folder, just doing an open/OK did not suffice ...